# Junit catch Expected Exception

Tags: junit4, expected-exception

I am doing a tutorial on how to use Expected Exception method to catch exception. I have 2 questions for the code.

1. I used single quote instead of double quote in the line shown below, the error message says *'Invalid character constant'*
   `exception.expectMessage(containsString('invalid age'));`

   2.The code executed fine in the Eclipse, but the console page doesn't show
   message in Class Person. Should I use keyword 'extends' to extend Class Person inside the class personTest?

   Please advise me why using single quote cause the error and how should modify my code so I can see the exception message from Person Class when execute the code in testPerson class. Thanks!

Tutorial code:

```
public class Person {
private final String name;
private final int age;
public  Person(String name, int age){
    this.name =name;
    this.age = age;
    if (age <= 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid age: " + age);
    }
}

}

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import org.junit.Test;

public class personTest {
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void testExpectedException(){
    exception.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    //exception.expectMessage(containsString('invalid age'));
    exception.expectMessage(containsString("Invalid age"));

    new Person("Joe", -1);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Strings**

'invalid age' is illegal in Java.  Single quotes are used for a single character.  As you note,d you have to use "invalid age" to make Java happy regarding syntax.

**Console**

The behavior is correct. JUnit is catching the exception so you don't see it on the console.

**Convention**

Java convention is to use camel case for classnames.  Beginning with an uppercase letter.  So it would be better if your class was named PersonTest.

Comment: Jeanne thank for the reply to show me the correct syntax, why console didn't show error message and the correct Naming convention in Java